# Jquery not working only on upper part of page

Tags: jquery

I have multiple items like this on a page (a gallery of items.)

```
 <li class="addto" id="<?=$ID;?>">
```

Then, I have some jquery that triggers some things to happen upon clicking the ".addto".

It really doesn't matter what the jquery is I have found.  If it is simply:

```
 <script>
 $(window).load(function() {

   $('.addto').click(function() {
   alert("HI");
  });
 });
 </script>
```

When I am at the top of the page, all works well and if I click the .addto item, the jquery fires the HI message.  I can continue to do this on the list of items until I scroll down to about halfway through the page.  Then, once I scroll down to a certain part, it stops working and nothing happens.  It happens on various pages of data, these are dynamic galleries, so it isn't just one gallery it is happening with.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or knows how to debug it?  No errors are being reported to me via the console.

Comment: If you have a lot of `.addto` elements - do not attach listener to each of them - use `.on()` method. http://api.jquery.com/on/  `$('body').on('click', '.addto', function(){ alert('Hi'); });` The same if you are adding elements with `.addto` dynamically. Instead of `'body'` you can use any static parent of the elements with `.addto`

Comment: Do you have a link to this page?

Comment: @Cheery This seems to have solved my problem.  If you want to post this as the official answer I will award it.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of `.addto` elements - do not attach listener to each of them as you are creating a large number of anonymous functions, one for every single listener. Instead use `.on()` method, which creates a single listener attached to the parent, which filters events by type and target. More you can read at http://api.jquery.com/on

Your code can be rewritten as

```
$('body').on('click', '.addto', function(){ 
  alert('Hi'); 
});
```

The same is true if you are adding elements with .addto dynamically as the new elements will not have attached listeners, but if the static parent has is - function will be called for them too. Instead of `'body'` you can use any static parent of the elements with `.addto`

Comment: Man, this was really helpful...  I had no idea this mattered.  Really helped me greatly.  Thanks so much. Cheery